# How do I publish a custom event after the current UoW transaction is successfully completed?

Tags: asp.net-core, unit-of-work, abp

There are predefined events like `EntityCreatedEventData` that are published after the transaction is successfully committed.

I would like to publish a custom `Event` after the transaction is successfully committed. Is that possible with the current API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is possible with the current API.

From https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Unit-Of-Work#other-iunitofwork-properties-methods:

> - `OnCompleted` method gets a callback action which is called when the unit of work successfully completed (where you can be sure that all changes are saved).

```cs
var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Current;
uow.OnCompleted(() =>
{
    await _eventBus.PublishAsync(new MyCustomEvent());
});
```

This is the same API that is used for `EntityCreatedEventData`.